# Solving $2x^{3}=3$ over $\mathbb{Z}_5$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Really new to dealing with $\mathbb{Z}_n$.

I'm trying to calculate $2x^{3}=3$ over $\mathbb{Z}_5$.

I did a similar question - solving $3x^{2}+x+1=0$ over $\mathbb{Z}_5$:

$$3x^{2}+x+1=0 \\\Rightarrow6x^{2}+2x+2=0\\
 \Rightarrow x^{2}+2x+1=-1=4\\
 \Rightarrow(x+1)^{2}=2^{2}\\
 \Rightarrow x+1=\pm2=2,3$$

But I have no idea how to solve $2x^{3}=3$. It feels like it should be easier.

Comment: Note that $2\cdot 3=1$ in $\Bbb Z_5$, so multiply with $3$. We obtain $x^3=-1$. This is easy to solve. Try out all $5$  elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are only 5 elements to check and $0$ and $1$ are easily ruled out. So just plug in $x = 2, 3, 4$ and see which of those work.

While we're here, let me point out that in $\mathbb{Z}_n$, there is a difference between a polynomial *function* and a polynomial that is not seen in $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$. For example, in $\mathbb{Z}_2$, $x = x^2$ as *functions* because $0 = 0^2$ and $1 = 1^2$. However, as polynomials they are different because they are made up of different terms. (This is something that was confusing to me when I first learned about polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}_n$.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What do you mean by plug?

Comment: @vesii I mean compute $2 \cdot 2^3, 2 \cdot 3^3, 2 \cdot 4^3$ and see which are equal to $3$.

Comment: so the answer is $x=2,4$?

Comment: @vesii just $4$, $2^4 =16 \equiv 1 \pmod 4$.

Comment: ops, yes you are right, thank you!